# Line Breaks in New Ticket comments

Tags: zendesk-api

Okay so I'm attempting to integrate opening ZenDesk tickets into our application. I'm currently able to post tickets with an api key successfully. However, when a comment contains line breaks it all comes crashing down.

When a comment contains a line break, or any of the following examples, I receive this error.

`{"error":"Unprocessable Entity","message":"Server could not parse JSON"}`

I've tried replacing the line breaks with:

- `\r\n`
- `\\r\\n`
- `\\n \\n`
- `\\r \\n`
- `</br>`
- `\<\/br\>`

I also attempted to Url encode the comment body but this wasn't decode on the other end so I ended up with an encoded comment on my ticket.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So my initial assumption that I needed to replace the line breaks was only part of the solution. The other part was that in the Zendesk JSON object, instead of using the `body` property I needed to use the `html_body` property [(seen here in the JSON format docs)](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/ticket_comments#json-format)

So the solution ended up looking something like this

```
let formattedBody = Regex.replace "(\r\n|\r|\n)" body "</br>"

(sprintf """{"ticket":{"subject": "%s", "comment": { "html_body": "%s" }}}""" subject formattedBody)
```

This rips out the line breaks and replaces it with html line breaks. Then the JSON that's posted to Zendesk has the `html_body` property in it instead of just `body`

Comment: Keep in mind though that when posting new comments to Zendesk as "html_body", the Markdown syntax is not supported there! So if need any fancy text formatting, you have to prepare the text (as HTML) yourself before submitting. The Markdown is supported only in "body" parameter per Zendesk API docs.